# how to do triple summations in matrices

Tags: r, loops, matrix, sum

I have got a triple summation expression like this

```
sum(l(from 1 to n))
   sum(i(from 1 to m))
       sum(t(from 1 to m)
          [phil_z1_1[i]*phil_z1_1[t}*I(X(l)<min(y(i),y(t))]
```

I have done:

```
set.seed(1234567)    
x <- rnorm(2900)
n <- length(x)
y <- rnorm(3000)*0.25
m <-length(y)    
z1 <- runif(m,min=0,max=1)
z2 <- runif(m,min=0,max=1)   
phil_z1_1 <- sqrt(12*(z1/z2)))
```

for `min(y[i],y[t])` I have done something like

```
y_m<-matrix(rep(y,length(y)),ncol=length(y))
y_m_t<-t(y_m)
y_min<-pmin(y_m_t,y_m)
```

After expanding the two inner summation, For example, for example `m=2,n=3`
I can put the original expression into the matrices like `x*A*x'`

where

```
x=[phil_z1_1[1] phil_z1_1[2]]
A is a 2*2 matrix 
A=[sum(from 1 to n) I(x[l]<=min(y[1],y[1]), sum(from 1 to n)    I(x[l]<=min(y1,y2); sum(from 1 to n) I(x[l]<=min(y[2],y[1]), sum(from 1 to n) I(x[l]<=min(y[2],y[2])]
```

Therefore,

```
x*A*x'=[phil_z1_1[1] phil_z1_1[2]]*[sum(from 1 to n) I(x[l]<=min(y[1],y[1]), sum(from 1 to n)    I(x[l]<=min(y1,y2); sum(from 1 to n) I(x[l]<=min(y[2],y[1]), sum(from 1 to n) I(x[l]<=min(y[2],y[2])][phil_z1_1[1] phil_z1_1[2]]'
```

Basically I want to create a m*m matrix for **A**, in which each individual element is equal to the sum of its corresponding part, for example, `sum(from 1 to n)x[l]<=min(y[1],y[1])` will be the a11 of **matrix A** I want to create

I have tried to use

```
args <- expand.grid(l=1:n, i=1:m, t=1:m)
args <- subset(args, x[l] <= pmin(y[i],y[t])-z1[i]*z2[t])
args <- transform(args, result=phil_z1_1[i]*phil_z1_1[t])

sum(args[,"result"])
```

But r cannot run the above programming, as the sample size of data set is too big, around 3,000.

Can someone tell me how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the `X` function? And why would you use `I()` in such an expression? I suspect you have mixed mathematical function notation with R indexing. You have no `y` function , but do have a `y` vector so would need to write: `y[t]`. (And 3,000 is a tiny dataset.)

Comment: You probably should make a much smaller test example with just one or two loops to make sure you grasp the basics of R syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a matrix approach for your triple sum

```
set.seed(1234567)    
n <- 10
x <- rnorm(n)

m <- 3000
y <- rnorm(m)/4
y_m <- pmin(matrix(rep(y,m), ncol=m, byrow=TRUE), y)


z1 <- runif(m,min=0,max=1)
z2 <- runif(m,min=0,max=1)   
phi <- sqrt(12*(z1/z2))
phi_m <- phi %o% phi

f1 <- function(l) sum(phi_m * (x[l] < y_m))
sum(sapply(1:n, f1))
[1] 242034847337
```

It is not lightning fast, but much faster than the data.frame approach

```
f2 <- function(lrng) {
    args <- expand.grid(l=lrng, i=1:m, t=1:m)
    args <- subset(args, x[l] <= pmin(y[i],y[t]))
    args <- transform(args, result=phi[i]*phi[t])
    sum(args[,"result"])
}
sum(sapply(1:n, f2)) # 90 times slower
[1] 242034847337
```